# how to solve Laravel routes conflict

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, routes

this is a simple code to search in laravel.
the route "product" has no problem at all, but,
when I use the route "searchproduct", the url in the browser looks like this:

> http://example.com/application/public/product/search?q=red+dead

so the application thinks that i'm trying to get the route "product" and send the parameter urlkey as "search?q=red+dead", which ofcourse throw an error.

**View**

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('searchproduct') }}" >
    <input id="q" name="q" class="q" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>

</form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('product/{urlkey}','ProductController@index')->name('product');
Route::get('product/search/{q?}','ProductController@search')->name('searchproduct');
```

how to solve this issue please?

Comment: Switch the order of the routes, so that it will match the specified "search" route before the "wildcard" route.

Comment: oh, just like that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define routes this order

```
Route::get('product/search/{q?}','ProductController@search')->name('searchproduct');
Route::get('product/{urlkey}','ProductController@index')->name('product');
```